# Installing ruby to specific directory/usb

Tags: install, ruby

I am trying to install ruby to a specific directory, a USB stick, so I can move the usb back and forth without having to install ruby on each machine I get to (I need ruby 2.0+). How can I do this?

I have been looking after stuff like setting RVM install directory and so forth, with no luck. The closest I found was [this description telling me how to move the entire RVM install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282509/how-to-change-rvm-install-location), which I don't want. I just want a simple ruby version on a usb stick.

On windows this was very easy: Run RubyInstaller, and point it to the USB. On OSx, well, that's another story.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Actually, I might be able to install it from the source. I will look into this and post answer if I get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out:

What you must do is download the [ruby source](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/), and extract it wherever. Then you have a folder named `ruby-2.1.2`, or something reflecting your ruby version.

Then, in terminal, `cd` to that directory. Then run:

```
./configure --prefix=/Volumes/USB_STICK_NAME/folder/to/install/into/osx_ruby
make
sudo make install
```

*Protip: drag-n-drop the ubs-folder you want into the terminal to get the desired folder path. Much easier than writing it*

That will install ruby into your usb-stick named "USB_STICK_NAME" under the folders `folder/to/install/into/osx_ruby`. Feel free to name it differently, but remember; The folder you select as install directory is where all the internal ruby stuff ends up,  like `bin`, `lib`. I would recommend naming that folder "osx_ruby" or something similar.

Hope someone finds this useful.